# Quick pitch-shifting from Audio Finder to DAW?

Tags: pitch-shifting, pitch, workflow

I just downloaded the Audio Finder demo, mainly because of its ability to preview my samples with pitch variations very quick.

Is there a way to export my samples with these pitch alterations directly to my DAW? It would be great for fast sound layering (for high quality pitch-shifting I use AudioSculpt from IRCAM).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just set the note and find the pitch you ware looking for. Then you can use the sample editor's tool for exporting. You can spot it directly to Pro Tools or convert it in to a new file.

Comment: Thanks Miguel!! Now, this software becomes very useful to me!

Comment: That kind of quick processing is very useful in some cases. It also works with AU and the rest of AudioFinder's editing options.

Comment: i tried this, seems the copy is created at the original file's sample rate. with sounds at lower sample rates you'll end up with a low-pass filtered file. might be a problem if you pitch things up.